# Unhandled Rejection SequelizeDatabaseError

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

I am working with Sequelize and I'm trying to insert one row into my User Column. However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Invalid object name 'User'.
```

I am connecting to a MSSQL server. I know that I have the basic connection right because I can run sequelize's plain queries via sequelize.query without issue. My suspicion is that I'm not specifying the schema or database correctly.

My model definition:

```js
var user = sequelize.define("User", {
    ID: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  unique: true,
  autoIncrement: true
 },
   FirstName: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING
 },
 LastName: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING
 },
 CreateDate: {
  type: Sequelize.DATE
 },
 UpdateDate: {
  type: Sequelize.DATE
 }
},{
 tableName: 'User',
 timestamps: false,
 freezeTableName: true
});
```

My attempt to use the model to create/INSERT a row into my pre-existing database.

```js
User.schema('Core');

User.create({ ID: '1', FirstName: 'Bobert', LastName: 'Jones'}).then(function(user) {
  console.log(user.get({
   plain: true
  }))
 });
```

When I used Sequelize's plain SQL to accomplish this I DID have to include the schema aka "insert into Core.User". Am I not specifying the schema correctly? I have tried adding it to my initial connection definition by adding "schema: 'Core'," before dialectOptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can specify schema in your sequelize constructor:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize("db",
    "user",
    "pass", {
        host: "localhost",
        port: "1206",
        dialect: "mssql",
        define: {
            schema: "core"
        }
    });
```

However, according to their [code](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/3e5b8772ef75169685fc96024366bca9958fee63/lib/model.js#L1041) what you are doing appears correct. In the sequelize constructor you can also turn logging on (logging: true). Logging should output the exact sql that is being constructed.

Comment: This worked for me! The real key was putting schema inside of "define". I'm still a little unsure why my previous setup wasn't working, but I'm happy to have something operational. At least in this one case.